# Change default editor to vim for _ sudo systemctl edit [unit-file] _

Tags: systemd, vim, editors

*[4.13.12-1-ARCH with gnome3 and gdm on Xorg]*

I already have set my VISUAL and EDITOR env-vars to `vim`. Similarly I did try `SYSTEMD_EDITOR="vim"; export SYSTEMD_EDITOR`  in my ~/.bashrc, to no avail.

When modifying unit files in Arch (systemd) via

```
 $ sudo systemctl edit _unit_
```

I find myself staring at `nano`. Life is too short and I want `vim` by all means. How do I do this ?

Comment: I have zero patience with Nano and prefer to kill a mosquito with a cannon. I delete Nano and place a symlink to vim in it's place. Done.

Comment: "sudo apt remove nano". Remove nano that will make vim as default

Answer (score 80, accepted):

First method, you can add this line to `~/.bashrc`:

```
export SYSTEMD_EDITOR=vim
```

And then `sudo visudo` and add this line:

```
Defaults  env_keep += "SYSTEMD_EDITOR"
```

Start new bash session to take effect, then run `sudo systemctl edit <foo>` as usual.

Second method is use `update-alternatives`:

Install your desired `editor`, e.g. `vim.gtk3`:

```
$ which editor
editor is /usr/bin/editor
$ sudo update-alternatives --install "$(which editor)" editor "$(which vim.gtk3)" 15
```

Then choose your desired `editor`:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config editor
There are 7 choices for the alternative editor (providing /usr/bin/editor).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/vim.gtk3    50        auto mode
  1            /bin/ed             -100       manual mode
* 2            /bin/nano            40        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/code        0         manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/gedit       5         manual mode
  5            /usr/bin/vim.basic   30        manual mode
  6            /usr/bin/vim.gtk3    50        manual mode
  7            /usr/bin/vim.tiny    15        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 6
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/vim.gtk3 to provide /usr/bin/editor (editor) in manual mode
```

Third method is direct set the `EDITOR` on runtime:

```
sudo EDITOR=vim systemctl edit <foo>
```

The precedence are **first method > third method > second method**.

Don't try to set "GUI" editor such as `gedit` because [Why don't gksu/gksudo or launching a graphical application with sudo work with Wayland?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w) and 
[Gedit uses 100% of the CPU while editing files](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/367372/comments/36)

Comment: Thanks 林果皞, but I really meant `vim`, not `gedit`.

Comment: @Cbhihe `gedit` is just an example to proved that even gui editor is working, of course you can use `vim` with this answer.

Comment: [UPDATE] I edited my answer to add advise don't set `gedit`.

Comment: The third method should have `SYSTEMD_EDITOR` instead of `EDITOR`.

Comment: Is there any way to use the `sudoedit` command for this (that is, have sudoedit launched with my regular, non-root user)?

Comment: It worked. Other option with file `.bashrc` or `.profile` didn't work, because my root doesn't have any `root` folder :)

Answer (score 26):

You are setting the variables for your own user, but are running the `systemctl` command as root (`sudo`). Therefore, the variables you've set for your user are irrelevant.

To fix this, you can either (but go with 1):

1. Run `sudo` with `-E` so it exports the current environment:

   ```
   sudo -E systemctl edit _unit_
   ```
2. Add the variable (you only need `SYSTEMD_EDITOR` for this) to root's `~/.profile`:

   ```
   export SYSTEMD_EDITOR="/bin/vi"
   ```

   Then run with

   ```
   sudo -i systemctl edit _unit_
   ```

Finally, note that you need to specify the full path to your editor, not just its name. So it's `/bin/vi` and not `vim`.

Answer (score 8):

I use a shell alias:

```
sc='sudo SYSTEMD_EDITOR=/bin/vi /usr/bin/systemctl'
```

Then just:

```
sc edit service-name
```

It's also useful for generally avoiding typing 7 out of the 9 characters of `systemctl` in cases like `restart`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The only ways that worked for me are:

- A root shell (`su` or `sudo -i`), setting `SYSTEMD_EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim`, then `systemctl edit <unit>`
- Setting `SYSTEMD_EDITOR`, then `sudo -E systemctl edit <unit>`
- `sudo SYSTEMD_EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim systemctl edit <unit>`

I tried setting `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` and `SYSTEMD_EDITOR` for bash and zsh, for user and root, but it only worked from a root shell, setting the variable after `sudo`, or using sudo with `-E`.

I also edited sudoers (`sudo visudo`) to add:
`Defaults  env_keep += "SYSTEMD_EDITOR"`
Still, I found the variable was not listed in `sudo systemctl show-environment` even though `sudo echo $SYSTEMD_EDITOR` showed vim.

I set the variable with:
`sudo systemctl set-environment SYSTEMD_EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim`
And confirmed with `sudo systemctl show-environment`.

Even after that though, the only ways that work for me are the ones listed at the top.